# ClassLoader.getResource returns odd path (maybe)?

Tags: java, path, classloader

When loading an asset such as a text file from the resources folder, the most common approach is to use ClassLoader to get the path:

```
String path = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("file.txt").getPath();
```

You can then use any of the many readers that java has to read the content of that file. But for some reason, `Paths.get(path)` is not happy with the path:

```
byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)) 
    -> throws java.nio.file.InvalidPathException when executed
```

ClassLoader.getResource(...).getPath() is returning:

```
/D:/Projects/myapp/build/resources/main/file.txt
```

`Paths.get()` doesn't like it. Apparently the ':' after `/D` is an 'Illegal char'. (Note that the path seems correct, the file is actually there)

Which one is causing the problem? Is `ClassLoader.getResource()` returning an invalid path or is `Paths.get()` acting up over nothing?

*Some time later*
It seems that there are multiple different formats for paths in java. The various frameworks don't appear to completely agree on what is right and what is wrong, therefore there are various discrepancies between the paths that they create and accept.

In this example, `Paths.get()` was in fact not expecting the leading slash in the path:

```
/D:/Projects/myapp/build/resources/main/vertex.vs.glsl <- EVIL
D:/Projects/myapp/build/resources/main/vertex.vs.glsl <- OK
```

I suppose that the question now is: How do I sanitise file paths returned by `ClassLoader.getResource()` for use with `Paths.get()` properly? Are there any other differences between their two file path formats?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. *"the most common approach"* is not necessarily the best :)
2. Take care which path you mean: [ClassLoader.getResource()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResources(java.lang.String)) returns a URL, which can have a [path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getPath()) component. However, this is not necessarily a valid file-path.
   Note, that there is also a method [Paths.get(URI)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get(java.net.URI)) which takes a [URI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) as parameter
3. The first slash in `/D:/Projects/myapp/build/resources/main/file.txt` just means, that this is an absolute path: see [Class.getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String))
4. I recommend, that you simply use [ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) when you want to read a file

*Update* to answer comment: "So why does Paths.get() not accept the absolute path?"

`Paths.get()` **does** accept absolute paths.
But you must pass a valid (file-)path - and in your case you pass the URL-path directly (which is not a valid file-path).

- When you call: `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("file.txt")` it returns a URL: `file:/D:/Projects/myapp/build/resources/main/file.txt`

  - this URL consists of the schema `file:`
  - and the valid (absolute URL)path: `/D:/Projects/myapp/build/resources/main/file.txt`
- you try to use this URL-path directly as a file-path, which is wrong

  - thus the [Paths.get(String,..)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...)) method throws an `InvalidPathException`

To convert the URL path to a valid file-path you could use the [Paths.get(URI)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get(java.net.URI)) method like so:

```
URL fileUrl = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("file.txt");
Path filePath = Paths.get(fileUrl.toURI());
// now you have a valid file-path: D:/Projects/myapp/build/resources/main/file.txt
```

Comment: So why does `Paths.get()` not accept the absolute path?

Comment: `Paths.get` returns type `Path`, not `String`?

Comment: @LeiYang right, I've fixed the type

Answer (score 0):

Please, have a look at the result of `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("file.txt")`. It's a URL. With `getPath()` then you just retrieve the path part of that URL, ignoring protocol and server part. Opening the path part as a file might work under certain circumstances (in the easy cases where file syntax and URL path syntax match), but don't do it in production code.

Why? When you leave your IDE and deliver your application as JAR or WAR, the resources will reside inside a ZIP-compressed file, and there will be no file "file.txt" that you can open, there's only an entry in a JAR or WAR file.

As @TmTron pointed out, I also recommend to use `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()`. That will work in all cases.